# Are there solar lights that can be put inside existing lamps?

Tags: lighting

We've got lamp posts in the garden that we're fond of, but the electrics were not very well installed (by the previous owner I might add). I've disconnected the electrics and would like to put a solar bulb or mass of LED lights inside the lamp houses with the charger discretely stuck in the ground nearby.

Are there lamps I can buy online or in the UK that would be suitable? If none are suitable, I might create a birds nest of an LED string of lights inside the lamp housing. Would that provide enough light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe buy some cheap solar lamps, and tear them apart to use guts to replace your existing lamps, but my guess is you're going to have trouble mounting the solar panels somewhere that doesn't look goofy. If you mount them away from the lamp itself, then you're going to have to run wiring (and as you said, that was not done well and has been disconnected). If you're willing to run new wiring, then you can definitely use low voltage LED bulbs, where you just need low voltage cable that goes back to a transformer somewhere (or battery + solar panel) - this is much easier and safer to install than high voltage cable (where you pretty much need to run it in a conduit anywhere underground).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the company [Nokero](http://www.nokero.com/) produces such a lamp. Small solar panels are integrated, and although the lamps *can* be screwed into regular fixtures, they do not use any external electricity and can be hung on a hook, nail or cable as well.